# Multiple sites on a single server with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm looking to stand up a number of Django websites via docker-compose, on a single server, and I'm having some trouble getting a starting config together. Can anyone point out obvious issues with the below?

the main root site container (website.com):

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
        env_file: prod.env
        environment:
            - DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=True
            - DJANGO_SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER_CHECK=True
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=website.com
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
            - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=website.com
        command: bash -c "
            python manage.py migrate --noinput &&
            python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
            gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
            "
        volumes:
            - .:/home/app
        networks:
            web:
                aliases:
                    - web
        expose:
            - 8000
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        image: postgres
        hostname: db
        env_file: prod.env
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres_db
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres_sa
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        networks:
            - web
        ports:
            - 5432:5432

    nginx-proxy:
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        build:
            context: nginx/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod.ssl
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - .:/home/app
            - static_volume:/home/app/staticfiles/
            - media_volume:/home/app/media/
            - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
            - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
            - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
            - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
        networks:
            - web
        ports:
            - 443:443
            - 80:80
        depends_on:
            - web

    nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
        image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        env_file: prod.env
        environment:
            - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=nginx-proxy
            - DEFAULT_EMAIL=email@website.com
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
            - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
            - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
            - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam:ro
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        depends_on:
            - nginx-proxy

networks:
    web:

volumes:
    postgres_data:
    conf:
    vhost:
    certs:
    html:
    dhparam:
```

###################################################################

one of the subdomain site containers on same server (sub.website.com):

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
        env_file: prod.env
        environment:
            - DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=True
            - DJANGO_SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER_CHECK=True
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=sub.website.com
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
            - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=sub.website.com
        command: bash -c "
            python manage.py migrate --noinput &&
            python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
            gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
            "
        volumes:
            - .:/home/app
        networks:
            - django
            - web
        expose:
            - 8000
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        image: postgres
        hostname: db
        env_file: prod.env
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres_db
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres_sa
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        networks:
            - web

networks:
    django:
        external:
            name: djangomango_web
    web:

volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

Comment: What sort of difficulties are you having?

Comment: Either the sub domain container was trying to access the same db as the root site (i.e. credential conflict). Or a ssl cert wasn't being issued to the sub domain. I've had to jump onto something else, and can't look at this again until later in the week. So putting here to see if someone can pick up something obvious, before I pick it back up.

Comment: why do you have 2 compose file ?